# Runtime error 1004 "_worksheet" midway through loop of all worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below block of code that I wrote a few months ago. This was working fine on all my files until today when I tried to run it. I have a new excel file that I am working with that pulls together multiple data files from a system and feeds those into a roll forward summary.

My code is simple and it loops through all the worksheets and sets my font and view settings.

However, when I run the file now, I get a

> run-time 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

I've tried to debug and step through the code and it will fail on the third tab on "ws.Select". I can't figure out why that tab is giving an issue if they are all worksheets. Am I missing something?

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Select
        ws.Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        ws.Cells.Font.Size = 11
        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
    
    Next ws
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I found the code working.

Comment: I'm only getting this error when I run in a specific workbook that another coworker had edited. He built the excel file by creating tabs and copying in tabs. I'm not sure what could cause this issue - is there a some sort of property on the imported tabs that make them a different type of worksheet?

Comment: Are there any hidden sheets?

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure not to run `ws.Select` on hidden sheets:

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet     
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then 'make sure to exclude hidden sheets
            ws.Select
            ws.Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
            ws.Cells.Font.Size = 11
            ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
            ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
        End If
    Next ws    
End Sub
```

---

Alternatively make them visible, do your changes and revert the original visibility state:

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet        
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        Dim OriginalVisibleState As Long
        OriginalVisibleState = ws.Visible
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible 'make it visible

        ws.Select
        ws.Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        ws.Cells.Font.Size = 11
        ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
        
        ws.Visible = OriginalVisibleState 'hide it if it was hidden before (revert to original visibility state)
    Next ws    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you - that was indeed the problem. Thank you!